# How to loop through an array of elements to check if classlist contains a value which is the same as any of the ids found in a different array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to loop through songs (an array/NodeList of elements) and see if an element's classlist includes a class that is the same as the id value of any of the items of a different array and if so console.log the name value from the corresponding array item.

Any help would be much appreciated.

```
const arr = [
    Object {
        name = nameOne,
        id = 1
    },
    Object {
        name = nameTwo,
        id = 2
    },
    Object {
        name = nameThree,
        id = 3
    },
    Object {
        name = nameFour,
        id = 4
    },
    Object {
        name = nameFive,
        id = 5
    },
    Object {
        name = nameSix,
        id = 6
    },
]

const songs = document.querySelectorAll('.songs')

songs.forEach(song => {
    if(song.classList.includes(?) {
        
    }
})
```

Comment: What have you tried so far to solve this on your own? -> [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: What does your html look like? Are there any errors in your console? Your `arr` is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Array.find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to find the item in the array whose `id` is present in the element's class list:

```js
const arr=[{name:"nameOne",id:1},{name:"nameTwo",id:2},{name:"nameThree",id:3},{name:"nameFour",id:4},{name:"nameFive",id:5},{name:"nameSix",id:6}];

const songs = document.querySelectorAll('.songs')

songs.forEach(song => {
  const item = arr.find(e => song.classList.contains(e.id))
  console.log(item?.name || "not found")
})
```

```html
<div class="songs"></div>
<div class="songs 1"></div>
<div class="songs"></div>
<div class="songs 2"></div>
<div class="songs"></div>
```